# How to monitor just t-sql commands in SQL Profiler?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, profiler, monitor

I have a trouble in monitoring t-sql commands, I want to monitor just commands like: select, insert, update or delete.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pick a trace template (such as Tuning) and use a filter.

Either filter by a particular login (such as your own login or a service's login), or a particular database.

For instance, to filter by database: Under Trace properties -> Events tab -> Select show all columns. Set a `Like` filter on database name.

I find setting a filter on the number of Logical `Reads` of say `> 10` reads, filters out most of the noise.

- [How to: Filter Events in a Trace](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175520%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)
- [Using SQL Server Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187929%28v=sql.105%29.aspx/css)

Answer (score 3):

Download Express Profiler From [CodePlex](http://expressprofiler.codeplex.com/)

You can get all your query after starting a trace. This can be used any machine.

Comment: This is sooooo good. Beats having to install the clunky default SQL Profiler.

Answer (score 2):

- Open Sql Profiler from: Programs -> Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 -> Performance Tools -> SQL Server Profiler
- Click on "New Trace" and Logon into database engine
- Click on "Show all events" checkbox
- In the events tree expand "TSQL" and check SQL:BatchCompleted, then check "Show all columns" and check item "TextData"
- Click Run button.