# How to check if SSAS Partitions are running in parallel or not using SQL Profiler?

Tags: oracle, ssis, ssas, msbi, sql-server-profiler

I am situation where I have to check and confirm whether SSAS partitions queries are running parallel or not while processing the SSAS cube using SSIS job. SSIS job/package using 'Analysis Services Processing Task' to process cube by selecting each object(dimensions and partitions) in it instead of selecting direct SSAS DB.

Can any one please guide how to check parallelism using sql profiler?

Also if anyone can point out why cube processing using above way is taking longer than the cube processing by SSIS job in which 'Analysis Services Processing Task' selecting ssas db name directly.

please help with any comments/ suggestions.

Many Thanks

Regards,

---

*Update:  My end db from which partitions will fetch the data is Oracle*

Comment: Is the issue solved?

Answer (score 1):

I think there is an easier way than using SQL Profiler, you can benefit from the amazing stored procedure `sp_whoisactive` to check what are the current query running on the server (Data Source SQL Database Engine) while processing the `Analysis Services Processing Task`.

Just download the stored procedure and create it on your master database.

- [sp_whoisactive homepage](http://whoisactive.com/)
- [How to Log Activity Using sp_whoisactive](https://www.brentozar.com/responder/log-sp_whoisactive-to-a-table/)

---

*Hint: In SQL Server Management Studio, go to data source properties and check the maximum allowed connections property, since it may prevent queries parallel execution*

Comment: thanks Yahfoufi, 
My end db from which partitions will fetch the data is Oracle.

Comment: @ScriptSoft then you have to try the other answer

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for an answer using SQL Profiler, you can simply create a trace to monitor the SQL Server that contains the data sources used by partitions. And while the partitions are processed if many SQL queries are executed in parallel then parallelism is achieved.

If you are new to SQL Profiler you can refer to the following links to learn how to monitor only T-SQL commands:

- [How to monitor just t-sql commands in SQL Profiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18669421/how-to-monitor-just-t-sql-commands-in-sql-profiler)
- [Use SQL Server Profiler to trace database calls from third party applications](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2040/use-sql-server-profiler-to-trace-database-calls-from-third-party-applications/)

---

But if you are looking for a simpler solution, then the other answer is what you are looking for.

Comment: Hello hadi,
I had used profiler couple of time, also url given does answer what I am looking for.
I just want to confirm if 2 commands/SQL queries starts at same time OR overlap their execution timing, does it mean they are running in parallel?
OR there are other parameters to decide parallelism in SQL profiler?

Comment: @ScriptSoft if more than one query are running at the same time than they are running in parallel.

Comment: @ScriptSoft i recommend reading the following article to learn more about setting processing degree of parallelism https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2005/administrator/cc966525(v=technet.10)#set-the-appropriate-values-for-parallel-processing